# Viewport.Unproject - Checking if a model intersects a large sprite

Tags: xna, 2d, 3d, collision-detection, vector

Let's say I have a sprite, drawn like this:

```
spriteBatch.Draw(levelCannons[i].texture, levelCannons[i].position, null, alpha, levelCannons[i].rotation, Vector2.Zero, scale, SpriteEffects.None, 0);
```

Picture levelCannon as being a laser beam that goes across the entire screen. I need to see if my 3d model intersects with the screen space inhabited by the sprite. I managed to dig up Viewport.Unproject, but that seems to only be useful when dealing with a single point in 2d space, rather than an area. What can I do in my case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you mean [`Viewport.Unproject`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.graphics.viewport.unproject.aspx)? This method is used to covert a point from screen space into world space. You can follow the instructions on the [MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.graphics.viewport.unproject.aspx) on how to convert a 2D screen space point into two separate 3D points that form a ray going into the screen.

From what I understand, you have a 2D line going across the screen and want to see what 3D objects are intersected by that line, like this?

[image]

I think what you can do is use [`Viewport.Unproject`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.graphics.viewport.unproject.aspx) four times: on the left side of the screen for the far and near plane, then the right side of the screen for the far and near plane (really you only need three of these points). With these points you can create a [`Plane`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.plane.aspx) which you should use with your collision detection to see which objects fall on that plane.

Comment: Yes, I edited the question to fix that mistake. This should do nicely.